# How to control read and write privileges of participating peers on hyper ledger fabric channel ledger?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Suppose there are 3 peers Peer1, Peer2 and Peer3 of Org1,Org2 and Org3 respectively are members of channel1.As per my understanding all these 3 peers would have same access privilege on channel ledger data. But my requirement is only Peer1 can add/update/read data on Ledger. Peer2 and Peer3 should have only read data privilege on this ledger. How it can be achieved ?

Comment: At this moment, your question is of poor quality. You can improve it by providing more details. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical private blockchain network scenario; that is, org1 owes and operates the network whereas org2 and org3 are read-only members of the network. The general set up is as following:

1. set up network ordering service system channel where only member is org1 who has authority to modify config and create channels
2. org1 admin creates an application channel and include org2 and org3 members as readers on the channel while org1's members are writers and admins
3. org2 and org3 (local) peer admins instruct their respective peers to join the application channel
4. Depending on the governance of the network, org2 and org3 peers may or may not be endorsing peers

You may see a similar example of this in [Fabric 1.4.2 document add org to a channel](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/channel_update_tutorial.html#prepare-the-cli-environment)
which uses the code from [the sample repo](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.4/first-network). Pay attention to the configtx.yaml file content. You could just remove org2 from there.

Comment: Hey, can you give some configtx.yaml structure for what you have just explained?